# Split set of data in the output using PHP

Tags: php

How to spit this set of data using php? this data generated from some php to my mysql database.

```
[{"id":"1","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Company","value":"Destination Queenstown"},{"id":"2","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Your Name","value":"Ella Zhang"}]
```

now i just need to get `id=2` and its value in the output.

Comment: Do you mean parsing JSON ?

Comment: hi rikesh...i don't know anything about json before. thank you for your references. problem solved ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a `JSON` data.Try with -

```
$array = '[{"id":"1","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Company","value":"Destination Queenstown"},{"id":"2","is_email":"false","add_to_day_hour_info":"false","add_to_day_hour_body":"false","translation":"Your Name","value":"Ella Zhang"}]';

$array = json_decode($array);

echo $array[1]->id;
```

Comment: Hi Noel, thanks for help.

how to implement json_decode in while loop? i tried it in my code but it returns empty

Comment: Add your code to loop

Comment: here is my code http://pastebin.com/i9z7YBwY i tried to use $array = json_decode($array, true); but still return with empty value

Comment: Why did you use `$array[1]`?

Comment: to parse json data for id:2